# use async.series or waterfall in a loop

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I am just learning to use async and I want to do something like this:

```
var listOfArguments = [];
async.waterfall([
getTheListOfArguments,
function(callback) {
  if (listOfArguments.lengh > 0) {
    doSomething(listOfArguments.shift());
  } else {
    callback(null, listOfArguments);
  }
}
], function(err, res) {
})
```

In fact I want getListOfArguments to read some list and keep it globally, then I want to loop over the doSomething function to get each element of the array as an input and move on to the next element *only when it's done* with the first (hence the use of async!), but this doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: And does `doSomething` return a promise, as it's surely async, otherwise non of this would be neccessary ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While i'm not quite sure what you are trying to achive, i believe the code you need might look more like this

```
var listOfArguments = [];

getTheListOfArguments(function(){
    // listOfArguments now contains some items, let's process it
    if(listOfArguments.length) doSomething();
});

function doSomething() {

    var item = listOfArguments.pop();

    // ... do your thing here

    // if we still have some items in the listOfArguments array doSomething again
    if(listOfArguments.length) return doSomething();

    // we are done, do something here
    console.log('Done');
}
```

Comment: There might be a maximum stack limit to the number of functions you can run at once. Is there an alternative option.

Comment: @FlynSequeira In the example above you only run the doSomething function one at a time. If you need to do something asynchronous then you might want to call the doSomething function after all async functions have finished. I can't see any reason to hit any stack limit.

Comment: Oh yes. Because of return.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this.

```
var listOfArguments = [];
var listOfTasks = [];


getTheListOfArguments(function(){
  listOfArguments.forEach(function(arg){
     listOfTasks.push(doSomething.bind(null, arg))
 });
});



async.series(listOfTasks, function(err, res) {
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option here would be async.whilst in your case.

The first parameter will be the test function. The second parameter will run as long as the first parameter will return true. The third parameter will run after the first parameter returns false or an error occurs.

The first parameter will be checked after every iteration of the doSomething function.

```
async.whilst(
    function() { return list_of_arguments.length > 0; },
    function(callback) {
        doSomething(list_of_arguments,(err, list_of_arguments)=>{
            if(err){
                callback(err,null)
            }
            list_of_arguments.shift();
            callback(null,list_of_arguments);
        });
    },
    function (err, list_of_arguments) {
        if(err){
            console.log(error)
        }
        else{
            // list of arguments is empty here
            console.log(list_of_arguments.length) //logs 0
        }
    }
);
```